# XSLT Issue trouble

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

have this problem
Inside one XML file I might happen to have one or multiple request tag, like following:

```
<notification>
    <data>
        <admin originator="" event_time="2015-02-28T02:26:42+02:00">
            <input>
                <request_set tx_id="Y2xfMDFfMDE6LWFjODQ2MTQ6Y2E3Mjo1NGVmYjA3NjoxNTE3ODA=#YWM4NDYxNDpjYTcyOjU0ZWZiMDc2OjE1MTc5Ng==" tx_timeout="2015-02-28T00:36:51.824Z" tx_command="start">
                    <request report="">
                        <update>
                            <account_data id="2005637" parent="3615732" Status="2" instance="1">
                                <info>
                                    <additional languageid="ARA" nwop="WMP" expdat="2015-08-17T00:00:00+02:00" exptyp="Deactivate" status="2" as="ACT/STD" dyn="ch=US,gn=,ct=1,enc=true,tp=TP_STUDENTS"/>
                                </info>

                            </account_data>
                        </update>
                    </request>
                    <request report="">
                        <update>
                            <account_data id="3615734" parent="3615732" Status="5" instance="1">
                                <info>
                                    <additional languageid="ARA" nwop="WMP" status="5" as="PAS/SUSP" dyn="ch=US,gn=,ct=1,enc=true,tp=TP_SHABABE"/>
                                </info>
                            </account_data>
                        </update>
                    </request>
                </request_set>
            </input>
        </admin>
    </data>
</notification>
```

Number of Request can be random, might be single or multiple.
My stylesheet applies following on Account ID

```
<xsl:variable name="ACID">
    <xsl:value-of select="/notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data/@id"/>
 </xsl:variable>
```

In this case for the second occurrence of Account ID (ACID) it will make a mistake cause it will still take the first one.
One thing I would like to apply is following:
If Status in the account_data is = 5 then take the account id in the same line.
Not sure you got my point, do you think thids is feasible ?
Any other way to do so ?
Many Thks in advance

Comment: No, I did not get your point. Show a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. For XSLT questions, this typically means a well-formed input XML, a complete XSLT stylesheet and all of the output you expect.

Comment: If there is no account_data with Status 5 what do you want to happen instead? Return the first one with any Status or nothing?

Comment: well...XML input is well formed. Complete XSLT unfortunately I can't :-( Trying to explain better, I missed one important part. There are 2 different XSLT that will apply same check (the oneI posted above) on the same input: the output coming from the second XSLT will report the first Account ID it meets (2005637), as all the XSLT using that check.what I need is to meet the second Account ID (3615734) which is the one I want to select. Only differantiation I have to select the second one is that Status=5 instead of =2. Hope I was a bit clearer. Thks for helping

Comment: Hi Stephanie...in case no Status 5 (which should never happen, report nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One thing I would like to apply is following: If Status in the
>   account_data is = 5 then take the account id in the same line.

I believe you mean:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data[@Status='5']/@id"/>
```

This will return the id of the (first) account_data whose Status is 5 ("3615734" in your example).

Comment: as simple as walk in the park (I have no clues about xslt anyways :-(. Many Many Thks

Comment: @MorganForever Please accept this answer if it solved your problem (actually, many of your previous questions have seemingly valid answers that you have not accepted).

Comment: @MorganForever - "This will return the id of the (first) account_data..." - This is only true for XSLT 1.0 or if there is only one account_data with a status of 5. If it's 2.0 and there is more than one account_data with a status of 5, you would need to change your `xsl:value-of` to `<xsl:value-of select="(/notification/data/admin/input/request_set/request/update/account_data[@Status='5'])[1]/@id"/>`

Comment: @DanielHaley True, but we know OP uses XSLT 1.0 from the description of the current behavior.

Comment: Yes that's true but future visitors might not realize that the current behavior is 1.0 specific and if the OP tries to upgrade to 2.0, the results would not be the same.

Comment: @DanielHaley "*future visitors might not realize that the current behavior is 1.0 specific*" Well, that's easy to fix.

Comment: @DanielHaley: thks for precious suggestion...but now the question is: What if I happen to have multiple request with the same State 5? How can I filter out different output/ACCID for different requests  ?

Comment: @MorganForever if you do have multiple requests with the same State 5, then you must supply some logic by which to determine which one is the correct one. Or take all of them.